# What is the fastest way to transfer files over high latency and high bandwidth link?

Tags: performance, networking, file-transfer, latency

I am trying to transfer files over a high latency and high bandwidth link. Unfortunately when I use `rsync` my transfer speed utilizes only a fraction of my available bandwidth. My total transfer time takes much longer than what I expected (i.e. transfer time = bytes / bytes-per-second available bandwidth)!

**What is the fastest way[1] to transfer files over high latency and high bandwidth link?**

So for example:

- latency is greater than 900 ms latency (round trip time)
- bandwidth 512 kbit/s

[1] i.e. utilize most of the available bandwidth

Answer (score 4):

When using `rsync` in a high latency and high bandwidth situation, your per connection transfer speed will be slower[1] than your available bandwidth. **For the example given, your expected transfer speed will be 56.25 KiB or less than 10% of the available bandwidth.**

**One solution is to run N `rsync` processes in parallel**:

```
#!/bin/bash

# tar up the files
tar -cvzf x.tar ${list_of_files}

# [optional]
# compute the md5sum
md5sum x.tar > x.tar.md5sum

# break the large tar file into N files (i.e. x.tar would become x.tar.1 ... x.tar.N)
# TODO

# start N `rsync` processes in parallel 
for ((i=1;i<=N;i++)); do rsync -avzh x.tar.${i} ${destination} & done

# wait for the transfers to finish
wait && echo "success" || echo "fail" && exit 1

# stitch the N files back together into x.tar
TODO

# [optional... but gives everyone a nice warm and fuzzy]
# copy the md5sum and verify your files (even though `rsync` already did so)
scp x.tar.md5sum ${destination}
ssh ${destination_machine} "cd ${path} && md5sum -c x.tar.md5sum && echo 'PASS (files verified with md5sum)' || echo 'FAIL (file verification failed md5sum)' && exit 1"
# done!
```

---

[1] Why is your transfer speed slow in this example?

In a word: [bandwidth-delay product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product) (three words actually)

This is an example of a high latency and high bandwidth link. Some might use a tool like `rsync` to transfer their data. If you run one instance of `rsync` (or something similar that also uses TCP or TCP-like protocol) you won't utilize the available bandwidth.

The reason for the slowdown has to do with the round-trip nature of TCP (or TCP-like protocols) requiring ACKs before sending more data. The problem is formally referred to as [bandwidth-delay product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product). Each connection speed will be limited by the latency more than the bandwidth.

Specifically for the example given, the theoretical speed will be 56.25 KiB or less than 10% of your available bandwidth.

The limitation is *per connection*. So using *just one* `rsync` for your file transfer will not fully utilize your bandwidth.

Solution 1:

Use a different program that doesn't use a TCP-like protocol but still guarantees your data through other means (a quick google search is something like [`uftp`](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) which transfers the data via UDP protocol instead of TCP). Unfortunately `uftp` is still not in many distro repos as of this writing.

Solution 2:

Continue using one `rsync` and change your TCP networking parameters on both sides but this requires expert knowledge that I don't readily have available at the moment.

Solution 3:

Run multiple `rsync` processes in parallel as described in the beginning of this question.

Comment: *change your TCP networking parameters*  [TCP scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option) should work in theory, and it should be enabled in the OP's OS.  Of course, theory isn't reality.

Comment: Author of [UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) here.  Even if it's not in your distro, building from source should be pretty simple.  Binaries for Windows are also available.